# Assertions in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

How to unit test a `CompleteableFuture`? This code should fail but it passed the test:

```
response.thenApply(HttpResponse::request)
        .thenAccept(Assertions::assertNull);
```

Comment: need a `join()` after `thenAccept(...)`?

Comment: Or simply block on the future and deal with it synchronously? Your test is obviously blocking so why bother with asynchrony?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah blocking worked. Just curious, is there any other way?

Comment: What would be another way? Your tests are obviously synchronous. I’m not really sure what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @MincongHuang I thought I waited on a latch but it was commented out, thanks for the pointer :)